# Host key verification failed. fatal: Could not read from remote repository

Tags: git, ssh

I started a new Project a GitLab.
After that i created a Repo, all works!
Then i generated a public key with (ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "my registrated email at git").
I added my Private Key to my personal GitLab Profile.

But when I want to test my connection with

> git push --set-upstream origin master

Git is telling me that:

> Host key verification failed. fatal: Could not read from remote
>   repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
>   exists.

I'am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This means the host key on the remote server has changed or that you're actually talking to a different host this time. Both scenarios can be fishy or can be benign so I would take extra steps to ensure you're talking to the right server. Verify with others what `nslookup your.origin.com` says to ensure you have the right dns address.

Comment: nslooup told me :
Server:  127.0.1.1
Address: 127.0.1.1#53
Non-authoritative answer:
"and then my git repo"